# Proof of the random sum formula

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $N$ and $X_1,X_2,...$ be independent random variables, each taking values in $\{0,1,2,...\}$. If the $X_i$ are identically distributed with common probability generating function $G_X$, then the sum
$$S=X_1+X_2+...+X_N$$
has probability generating function
$G_S(s)=G_N(G_X(s))$.

Now I'm having trouble understanding part of the proof for this theorem.
The proof goes as follows:
\begin{align}
G_S(s)&=\mathbb{E}(s^{X_1+...+X_N})\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb{E}(s^{X_1+...+X_N}|N=n)\mathbb{P}(N=n)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb{E}(s^{X_1+...+X_n})\mathbb{P}(N=n)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty G_X(s)^n\mathbb{P}(N=n)\\
&=G_N(G_X(s))
\end{align}
I understand everything exept the part $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb{E}(s^{X_1+...+X_N}|N=n)\mathbb{P}(N=n)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb{E}(s^{X_1+...+X_N})\mathbb{P}(N=n)$.
I don't know how or why $\mathbb{E}(s^{X_1+...+X_N}|N=n)$ is equal to $\mathbb{E}(s^{X_1+...+X_N})$ here.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The third line is wrong. You should have $\mathbb{E}(s^{X_1+...+X_n})$ here.

Comment: It should be $\mathbb E[s^{X_1 + ... + X_N} | N=n ] = \mathbb E[s^{X_1 + ... + X_n} | N=n] = \mathbb E[s^{X_1 + ... + X_n}]$ (i.e, in the latter you have index $n$, not $N$). It follows from independence of $N$ and $\{X_i\}_{i \ge 1}$.

Comment: Oh I see now I miswrote the $n$ to an $N$ in my notes. Thanks for that!